# Cannot do Eager Loading Sequelize

Tags: javascript, api, sequelize.js

I have a problem when I want to make a data call with sequelize.

Here is my exercise model:

**models/exercise.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const exercises =  sequelize.define('exercises', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull : false,
        unique: {
          msg: 'Le nom est déjà pris.'
        }
      },
      muscle1:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull : true,
        references: {
          model: 'muscular_groups',
          key:'id'
        } 
      },
      muscle2:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull : true,
        references: {
          model: 'muscular_groups',
          key:'id'
        }
      },
      muscle3:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull : true,
        references: {
          model: 'muscular_groups',
          key:'id'
          }
      },
      cat1: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull : true,
        references: {
          model: 'finalities',
          key:'id'
          }
      },
      cat2: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull : true,
        references: {
          model: 'training_types',
          key:'id'
          }
        },

      video :{
        type : DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
          isUrl: { msg: 'Utilisez uniquement une URL valide pour la vidéo.' }
        }
      },
    },{
      timestamps: true,
      createdAt: 'created',
      updatedAt: true
    });

    

    exercises.associate = (models) => {
      exercises.belongsTo(models.muscular_groups, {
        foreignKey: 'muscle1',
        foreignKey: 'muscle2',
        foreignKey: 'muscle3'
      });
    };
    exercises.associate = (models) => {
      exercises.belongsTo(models.finalities, {
        foreignKey: 'cat1'
      });
    };
    exercises.associate = (models) => {
      exercises.hasMany(models.circuit_exercises, {
        foreignKey: 'id_exercise'
        
    });
  };
  exercises.associate = (models) => {
    exercises.hasMany(models.multiple_set_exercise, {
      foreignKey: 'id_exercise'
      
  });
};
exercises.associate = (models) => {
  exercises.hasMany(models.warmups, {
    foreignKey: 'id_exercise'
    
});
};    
    return exercises;
};
```

Here is my muscular_group Model :

**models/muscular_group.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const muscular_groups =  sequelize.define('muscular_groups', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull : false,
        unique: {
          msg: 'Le nom est déjà pris.'
        }
      },
    },{
      timestamps: true,
      createdAt: 'created',
      updatedAt: true
    });

    muscular_groups.associate = (models) => {
        muscular_groups.hasMany(models.exercises, {
          foreignKey: 'muscle1',
          foreignKey: 'muscle2',
          foreignKey: 'muscle3'
      });
      };
       
    return muscular_groups;
};
```

**My query**

```
const {Exercise} = require('../db/sequelize')
const muscular_group = require('../models/muscular_group')

//Find all
exports.findAll = async (req,res) => {
      Exercise.findAll({
        include : {model : muscular_group,required : true}
      })
      .then(exercise => {
        const message = 'La liste des exos a bien été récupéré.'
        res.json({ message, data: exercise })
      })
  }
```

**My error :**

"include.model.getTableName is not a function"

**what I expect :**

I would like to have this result and then use it on a front end but I can't. I have tried everything to fix the problem.

```
"data": [
.
.
.
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Australian Pull Up",
"muscle1": {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "Biceps"
},
"muscle2": {
   "id" : 3,
   "name" : "Triceps"
},
"muscle3": {
   "id" : 15,
   "name" : "Quadriceps"
},
"cat1": {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "CNS"
},
"cat1": {
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "CPN"
},
"video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7viJ8F7FuM",
"created": "2023-01-05T16:51:59.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2023-01-05T17:02:38.000Z"
},
.
.
.
```

**what I don't want to have :**

```
"data": [
.
.
.
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Australian Pull Up",
"muscle1": 5,
"muscle2": 6,
"muscle3": 2,
"cat1": 2,
"cat2": 1,
"video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7viJ8F7FuM",
"created": "2023-01-05T16:51:59.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2023-01-05T17:02:38.000Z"
},
.
.
.
```

***UPDATE :***

**Here is my app.js**

```js
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const sequelize = require('./src/db/sequelize');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require ('express');
const AdminJS = require('adminjs')
const AdminJSExpress = require('@adminjs/express')
const AdminJSSequelize = require('@adminjs/sequelize')
const adminJS = require('./src/routes/admin.router');
const port = process.env.PORT||3000
const app = express()
const router = AdminJSExpress.buildRouter(adminJS)

AdminJS.registerAdapter(AdminJSSequelize)  

//initialisation
sequelize.initDb()


//Middleware
app
.use(favicon(__dirname + '/favicon.ico'))
.use(bodyParser.json())
.use(cors())
.use(adminJS.options.rootPath, router)

//Vérifie qu'on est bien en ligne grace à Heroku
app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.json('Hello bg, bienvenu !')
})

//Ici, nous placerons nos futurs points de terminaison.

require('./src/routes/pokemon.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/auth.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/user.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/order.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/stripe.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/exercise.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/muscular_group.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/finality.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/training_type.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/circuit.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/circuit_exercise(junction).route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/multiple_set.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/warmup.router')(app)
require ('./src/routes/finisher.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/corpse.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/corpse_circuit.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/corpse_multiple.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/training.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/corpse_exercise.route')(app)


// On ajoute la gestion des erreurs 404
app.use(({res}) => {
    const message = 'Impossible de trouver la ressource demandée ! Vous pouvez essayer une autre URL.'
    res.status(404).json({message})
})


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Notre application Node est démarrée sur : http://localhost:${port}`))
```

**Here is my db/Sequelize :**

```js
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const sequelize = require('./src/db/sequelize');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const cors = require('cors');



const express = require ('express');
const AdminJS = require('adminjs')
const AdminJSExpress = require('@adminjs/express')

const AdminJSSequelize = require('@adminjs/sequelize')
AdminJS.registerAdapter(AdminJSSequelize)


const adminJS = require('./src/routes/admin.router');

const port = process.env.PORT||3000
const app = express()

const router = AdminJSExpress.buildRouter(adminJS)

//Middleware
app
.use(favicon(__dirname + '/favicon.ico'))
.use(bodyParser.json())
.use(cors())
.use(adminJS.options.rootPath, router)


//Init 
sequelize.initDb()





//Vérifie qu'on est bien en ligne grace à Heroku
app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.json('Hello bg, bienvenu !')
})

//Ici, nous placerons nos futurs points de terminaison.

require('./src/routes/pokemon.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/auth.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/user.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/order.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/stripe.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/exercise.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/muscular_group.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/finality.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/training_type.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/circuit.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/circuit_exercise(junction).route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/multiple_set.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/warmup.router')(app)
require ('./src/routes/finisher.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/corpse.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/corpse_circuit.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/corpse_multiple.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/training.route')(app)
require ('./src/routes/corpse_exercise.route')(app)


// On ajoute la gestion des erreurs 404
app.use(({res}) => {
    const message = 'Impossible de trouver la ressource demandée ! Vous pouvez essayer une autre URL.'
    res.status(404).json({message})
})


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Notre application Node est démarrée sur : http://localhost:${port}`))
```

It's been weeks and I can't seem to solve this problem.  :
**EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: muscular_groups is not associated to exercises!**

Comment: I think, what might be the error is, the variable muscular_groups is a function, you need to call this function to create the model.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have several problems:

1. You defined several `foreignKey` in the same association and just like in any other JS-object only the last `foreignKey` key will take effect. You need to define **three** separate associations with different aliases in order to define three links:

```js
exercises.belongsTo(models.muscular_groups, {
        foreignKey: 'muscle1',
        as: 'Muscle1'
});
exercises.belongsTo(models.muscular_groups, {
        foreignKey: 'muscle2',
        as: 'Muscle2'
});
exercises.belongsTo(models.muscular_groups, {
        foreignKey: 'muscle2',
        as: 'Muscle2'
});
```

That would lead to the following result:

```json
{
...
"muscle1": 5,
"muscle2": 6,
"muscle3": 2,
"Muscle1": {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "Biceps"
},
"Muscle2": {
   "id" : 3,
   "name" : "Triceps"
},
"Muscle3": {
   "id" : 15,
   "name" : "Quadriceps"
},
...
},
```

and yes, you should distinguish foreign key columns and loaded associated model instances (I just changed the case of the first letter for demonstration purposes).
The same goes for muscular_groups:
Instead of repeating the same option in one association:

```js
muscular_groups.associate = (models) => {
        muscular_groups.hasMany(models.exercises, {
          foreignKey: 'muscle1',
          foreignKey: 'muscle2',
          foreignKey: 'muscle3'
      });
      };
```

you need to define **three** associations:

```js
muscular_groups.associate = (models) => {
        muscular_groups.hasMany(models.exercises, {
          foreignKey: 'muscle1',
          as: 'Muscle1Exercises'
      });
        muscular_groups.hasMany(models.exercises, {
          foreignKey: 'muscle2',
          as: 'Muscle2Exercises'
      });
        muscular_groups.hasMany(models.exercises, {
          foreignKey: 'muscle3',
          as: 'Muscle3Exercises'
      });
      };
```

2. You repeated the definition of `associate` function several times with th different associations and for the same reason as I mentioned in p.1 you 'll end up with the last definition. You should place all associations one after another in only one `associate` function of a certain model:

```js
exercises.associate = (models) => {
  exercises.belongsTo(models.muscular_groups, {
        foreignKey: 'muscle1',
        as: 'Muscle1'
  });
  exercises.belongsTo(models.muscular_groups, {
        foreignKey: 'muscle2',
        as: 'Muscle2'
  });
  exercises.belongsTo(models.muscular_groups, {
        foreignKey: 'muscle2',
        as: 'Muscle2'
  });
  exercises.belongsTo(models.finalities, {
        foreignKey: 'cat1'
  });
  exercises.hasMany(models.circuit_exercises, {
        foreignKey: 'id_exercise'
  });
  exercises.hasMany(models.multiple_set_exercise, {
      foreignKey: 'id_exercise'
  });
}
```

3. As soon as you registered all models in the `db/sequelize` module you should use them only from this module nevertheless you use it as a main modle to call `findAll` or to indicate them in `include` options of `findAll`:

```js
// I assume you named `muscular_group` model as MuscularGroup in `sequelize` module
const {Exercise, MuscularGroup } = require('../db/sequelize')

//Find all
exports.findAll = async (req,res) => {
      Exercise.findAll({
        include : [{
          model : MuscularGroup,
          required : true
        }]
      })
      .then(exercise => {
        const message = 'La liste des exos a bien été récupéré.'
        res.json({ message, data: exercise })
      })
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your quickly answer but it doesn't work. The error code : EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: muscular_groups is not associated to exercises!

Comment: I added a block about `muscular_groups` associations as well, please look at it